# Logistic Tensor Regression

Tags: logistic, python, gradient-descent, theano, tensor

Say there are users and they view articles and click (or not click) on articles. I represent the $i$-th user as $x_i$, a $D \times1 $ vector and $j$-th article as $z_j$, a $C \times 1$vector. The reward (click) of user $i$ on article $j$ is $r_{ij}$.

Now say there is a tensor indicator $s_{ij} = \Sigma_{a=1}^C\Sigma_{b=1}^D x_{i,b}z_{j,a}w_{a,b}$. In matrix terms $s_{ij} = x_i^TWz_j$.

$z_{j,a}$ is the $a$-th feature of $z_j$.$x_{i,b}$ is the $b$-th feature of $x_i$. And $w_{a,b}$ represents the affinity of these two features.

I want to use logistic regression to determine W.

So lets say, $p(r_{ij}|s_{ij})=\frac{1}{1+exp^{-r_{ij}s_{ij}}}$

Is it correct to say that the gradient of the cost function is $w_{a,b}-\Sigma_{i,j}r_{i,j}x_{i,b}z_{j,a}(1-p(r_{ij}|s_{ij}))$

If the above it correct, is it correct to say the gradient descent would be
$$
w_{a,b} = w_{a,b}-\alpha[w_{a.b}-\Sigma_{i,j}r_{i,j}x_{i,b}z_{j,a}(1-p(r_{ij}|s_{ij}))]
$$

I have written the following python code to generate this. Is it correct or is there a better way to do this?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
   data_matrix =np.random.rand(8,6)
   print gradient_decent((3,2))

def gradient_decent(dimension, iterations=10):
   weights = np.ones(dimension)
   alpha = 0.001
   for k in range(iterations):
       gradient_error = weights_by_user_article_features(weights)
       estimated_weights = np.subtract(weights,gradient_error)
       weights = np.subtract(weights,estimated_weights)
   return weights

def weights_by_user_article_features(original_weights):
    weights = np.zeros(original_weights.shape)
    for j in range(0, 3):  # number of user features
        for k in range(3, 5):  # number of article features
            for i in range(0, 8):  # number of records
                sigmoid_tensor = tensor_indicator(original_weights,np_data_matrix[i][:]) * np_data_matrix[i][5]
                predicted_reward = sigmoid(sigmoid_tensor)
                reward_error = 1 - predicted_reward
                error = np_data_matrix[i][j] * np_data_matrix[i][k] * np_data_matrix[i][5] * reward_error               
                weights[j][k - 3] = weights[j][k - 3] + error           

    return weights
```

This question is related to this paperhttp://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~chuwei/paper/isp781-chu.pdf.